# Can we launch a deployment in Kubernetes with time limit if not then is any alternative available?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to find a way through which we can launch a deployment for some limited time which we set at the time of launch

Comment: Maybe you would like to use [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to run a Job in that case, it will run a pod and when you will specify the activeDeadlineSeconds it will be terminated after those second had passed.

you can read it all here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/